# How do I convert the text to remove words with one letter?

Tags: text-processing, string

How do I convert the text of the input stream in the following way: skip single letter words. If the word contains one number and one letter, it should also be omitted.

I have a `Text1.txt` file and rewrite the converted text into a `Text2.txt` file.

Text1.txt contains:

```
I like to be at home alone.
Today I2 am alone at home and can rest.
```

Text2.txt contains result:

```
 like to be at home alone.
Today am alone at home and can rest.
```

This text is in ASCII format.

There are several lines, possible repetitions of é and not only, it also does not contain type 111aaa.
I use one of the latest versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example input and the output you expect. Make sure to cover all possible cases in your example, and specify if this is ASCII text or UTF-8 or something else. Do you have one string per line? Multiple? Is `é` one letter? Does `111aaa` contain one number and one letter or 3 numbers and 3 letters (i.e. how should we deal with duplicates)? Also tell us what operating system you are using so we know what tools you have available.

Comment: Thanks. Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your text as code (I have done this now). In your example, if I have formatted it correctly, you show that `I` followed by a space should be replaced by `I` (so the space remains) but when `I2` is replaced, the space after it is also gone since there isn't an extra space between `Today` and `alone`. Which one is correct? And if your text contains `é`, the it cannot be ASCII since `é` isn't an ASCII character. What is the output of `file Text1.txt`?

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Spaces do not matter. Yes, sorry the text does not contain é.

Comment: What is "a number"? Is "1.34" a number, or "1.23e-12", or "0x77ff", "XXII"? Can we assume that you mean "a single digit"?

Comment: Of course it can be considered  "a single digit".

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\<[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]?\>//g' input_file
like to be at home alone.
Today  am alone at home and can rest.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'for .words() { print($_, " ") if .subst(:g, / \d /).chars > 1}; "".put;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
I like to be at home alone.
Today I2 am alone at home and can rest.
```

Sample Output:

```
like to be at home alone. 
Today am alone at home and can rest.
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. Briefly, line are read with the familiar `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags.

Each line is broken into whitespace-separated `words`, and [using `.subst(:g, / \d /)`], if non-`\d` digit `chars` of each word is numerically greater than one, the word (represented by the `$_` topic variable inside the curly-braces) is `print`ed, followed by whitespace `" "`.

At the conclusion of processing of each line, a newline is printed with `"".put` ( ...`put` means *print-using-terminator*).

https://raku.org
https://rakudo.org

Comment: i need to use it in the bash file creation then how?

Comment: @Denchik you can re-direct output into a new file, `~$ raku -e '...;'  your_input_file  > new_output_file`, or (if necessary) `~$ raku -e '...;'  <  your_input_file  > new_output_file`  . HTH.